# Why does Hong Kong have one of the best natural harbours in the world that can protect ships from the typhoon winds?

Tags: tropical-cyclone

My question in this post's title is predicated on [Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1fz39u/why_did_the_british_only_take_hong_kong_after_the/cafaj7u/) -

> Hong Kong was perfect for the British as a staging point from which to trade with China. **This was because Hong Kong has one of the best natural harbours in the world which was capable of protecting ships from the typhoon winds.** Also due to the British superiority in naval warfare Hong Kong could be easily defended from attacks. The taking of Hong Kong was primarily to establish a base from which Western (not just British) traders were able to sell opium to the Chinese without the Chinese being in a position to stop them. As far as I am aware there was never a desire to invade China, just trade for its silk, teas and manufactured goods.

I've riffled through some [satellite views](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1344&bih=613&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=uKz1XLPpCtKAtgWamI5Q&q=hong+kong+satellite+view&oq=hong+kong+satellite+view&gs_l=img.3..0.19010.19010..19596...0.0..0.126.126.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.n0iL-t6yC5U#imgrc=_) of HK, but I can't espy

1. which harbour is the one? [Victoria Harbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Harbour)?
2. what makes HK so "capable of protecting ships from the typhoon winds"?

The [picture beneath](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-satellite-view-of-hong-kong-this-image-was-compiled-from-data-acquired-112373063.html) "was compiled from data acquired by Landsat 8 satellite in 2015."

[image]